# How to trap a copy/move-file operation in a custom filesystem based on Fuse?

Tags: python, fuse

I`m implementing a custom filesystem on Ubuntu using Fuse, but I need to trap when a copy or move operation occur. Right now all I see are when some file are opened for writing or reading, but I need to see these operations in context so I can see what file are being copied or moved.

Any hints?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that using [pyfilesystem](http://code.google.com/p/pyfilesystem/) to create a filesystem and mounting it using the fs.expose.fuse in pyfilesystem worked very well. Look into that. I will. Thank you.

Comment: This accepted answer is incorrect, one can't trap on file copy, whatever wrapper over FUSE may use. The file copy operation on linux is open original file for read, open destination file for writing then read write content.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is probably not easily done, considering that a "copy" or "move" program could do just what you see - open a file and write to it. That's a perfectly good way of copying a file.

Even if you can see what actual binary is doing it, that wouldn't give you enough information to know if this was a copy, a move or simply a program writing data to a file.

If you tell us why you need to do this, then maybe someone can suggest another solution, that fulfills your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Copy is as Weholt said: difficult to trap because it is basically the same as creating a new file and writing to it.

Move is the same operation as a rename.